# gCloud instance: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

Tags: go, ubuntu, ssh, gcloud

I'm getting the following error when I try to ssh into a Ubuntu 22.04 gcloud instance:

Ubuntu Version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Error:

```
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

This error only happens when I use the golang ssh module [goph](https://github.com/melbahja/goph), but I'm able to ssh when ssh manually with: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa 34.132.133.12`.

Here is my connect snippet:

```
func Connect(privateKey, username string, ip net.Addr) (*goph.Client, error) {
    // Start new ssh connection with private key.
    priKey, err := goph.Key(privateKey, "")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Could not get privateKey: %v error: %v", privateKey, err)
    }

    c := 0
    for {
        log.Printf("Ssh to: %v", ip)

        s := spinner.New(spinner.CharSets[9], 100*time.Millisecond) // Build our new spinner
        s.Start()
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)
        s.Stop()

        client, err := goph.NewUnknown(username, ip.String(), priKey)
        if err != nil {
            c++
        } else {
            log.Printf("Connected to: %v", ip.String())
            return client, nil
        }

        if c >= 3 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Could not connect to %v, error: %v", ip.String(), err)
        }
    }
}
```

My code is able to ssh when running against this Ubuntu gCloud Version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I tried many solutions like changing the private key permission to `600` which was already setup. I also did other suggestion to `ssh-add private key` and still having the same issue.

Also I ran verbose when ssh into both ubuntu version and both OS accepted publickey:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key:
```

The creation and setting up of this instance is done by using the gCloud golang client.
It seems that it is a settings that needs to be done in the instance since I'm able to ssh on older Ubuntu versions.

Comment: If this works: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 34.132.133.12` then you have corrupted your keys. The SSH client uses the **Private Key** to connect and not the **Public Key**. By convention `id_rsa` is the private key and `id_rsa.pub` is the public key. You can tell which file is which key by looking at the first line.

Comment: Was a typo, I'm able to ssh using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa 34.132.133.12`

Comment: Are you using the same username? You are using a default username in your command.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug on https://github.com/melbahja/goph/issues/26. When I searched before I posted the question, I did not realize that I left the open issue flag on, so it did not show this bug. So I went back to double-check and saw the issue.

I updated all my modules since I don't have much by doing the following:

```
go get -u ./...
go mod tidy
```

Now I'm able to ssh. Thanks